# Ember Data belongsTo Association (JSON format?)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, active-model-serializers

I have two models 'Author' and 'Publisher' (Rails), with a publisher hasOne author / author belongsTo publisher relationship.

I have the Ember models setup correctly -- [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndreckshage/6Z2AL/) -- and the associations working when I manually push into the store. But only the publisher records are created when requesting /publishers index.

I've tried several types of JSON responses:

Publishers with author

```
{
    "publishers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test P 1",
            "author": 1
        }
    ],
    "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test A 1",
        "publisher": 1
    }
}
```

Publishers with authors

```
{
    "publishers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test P 1",
            "author": 1
        }
    ],
    "authors": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test A 1",
        "publisher": 1
    }]
}
```

Publishers with author embedded

```
{
    "publishers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test P 1",
            "author": {
              "id": 1
              "name": "Test A 1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ActiveModelAdapter`/`ActiveModelSerializer` expects `_id`/`_ids` to be appended on relationships

```
{
    "publishers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test P 1",
            "author_id": 1
        }
    ],
    "authors": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test A 1",
        "publisher_id": 1
    }]
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Z2AL/1/

Comment: Is this still the case? [This](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.ActiveModelAdapter.html#method_findMany) and [this](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.ActiveModelSerializer.html#method_serialize) lead me to believe otherwise.

Comment: Yes, that documentation is automatically generated and  the active model adapter and serializer extend the json adapter and serializer which works without ids.  http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.ActiveModelSerializer.html#method_serialize and https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.8/packages/activemodel-adapter/lib/system/active_model_serializer.js#L86

Answer (score 0):

Adding a link to ember-data issue in case it helps anyone -- [single object push payload](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1468#issuecomment-31679465)