# Ember data not loading nested hasMany

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

## The Problem

I have a Rails 4 backed Ember app that needs to iterate over some children, and then iterate over that child's children. The setup is Session -> hasMany -> Annotations -> hasMany -> Indicators.

I can load the /session/1 show template and display the session's properties. I can also iterate over my session's annotations and display the annotation's text. However When I iterate over the annotation's indicators, nothing shows up. If I output `{{#with annotation}}{{indicators}}{{/with}}` I just get `<DS.PromiseArray:ember802>`

Ember makes AJAX calls to /sessions/1 and /annotations?ids%5B%5D=113&ids%5B%5D=112. However it never makes a call to /indicators.

I've seen other posts that describe the same issue, but the solutions for those often came down to camel casing etc. In this case, since /indicators is never even being called, what am I doing wrong?

## Environment

```
ember.js - 1.5.1  
ember-data.js - 1.0.0-beta.7  
Written in CoffeeScript
```

## Ember Setup

```
Insight.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({})  
Insight.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({})
```

## Models

```
App.Indicator = DS.Model.extend {
  title:      DS.attr 'string'
}

App.Annotation = DS.Model.extend {
  text:         DS.attr 'string'
  session:      DS.belongsTo 'session', inverse: 'annotations'
  indicators:   DS.hasMany 'indicator', async: true
}

App.Session = DS.Model.extend {
  subject: DS.attr 'string'
  students: DS.attr 'number'
  time: DS.attr 'string'
  annotations: DS.hasMany 'annotation', async: true
}
```

## Routes

```
App.SessionRoute = Ember.Route.extend {
  model: (params)->
    return @store.find('session', params.session_id)`
```

## Session Show Template (Relevant Portion)

```
<section class='content'>
  {{#each annotation in annotations itemController="annotation"}}
    {{#with annotation}}
      <li {{bind-attr class="isCompleted:completed isEditing:editing"}}>
          {{#if isEditing}}
            {{edit-annotation class="edit" value=bufferedText focus-out="doneEditing" insert-newline="doneEditing" escape-press="cancelEditing"}}
          {{else}}
              {{text}}
            </div>            
          {{/if}}
          {{#each indicator in indicators}}
            <button>{{indicator.title}}</button>
          {{/each}}
      </li>
    {{/with}}
  {{/each}}
  {{view Ember.TextField id="new-annotation" placeholder="Enter an annotation" valueBinding="newAnnotation" action="createAnnotation"}}
</section>
```

## JSON GET Payloads

```
{"session":{
  "id":4,
  "subject":"Name of Subject",
  "students":1,
  "time":"08:52",
  "annotations":[113,112]}
}

{"annotations":
  [
    { "id":112,
      "text":"this is my first annotation",
      "session":4,
      "indicators":[1]
    },
    { "id":113,
      "text":"This annotation has indicators",
      "session":4,
      "team_member":8,
      "indicators":[1,2]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in JSON format.

Format that you're using is the format that is accepted by the RESTAdapter

```
data: [
  title: "Some Title",
  items: [1,2]
]
```

ActiveModelAdapter however expects the data to be in this format:

```
data: [
  title: "Some Title",
  item_ids: [1,2]
]
```

To solve the problem you can either swap to RESTAdapter OR change the data producer to produce proper format instead.

[JSBin with above code made working](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yubari/3/edit) and 
[other question that reference the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954980/ember-data-belongsto-association-json-format).